# Data not showing in collapsible div inside asp:Repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an aspx page which shows a group of data. The outer most div is  collapsible, which works fine. Then I have a asp:repeater to show each record in my list of data, I then have another collapsible div for each record. but when I put this last div in my records do not show here is the code piece:

```
<div id="EmailEvents" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d" style="margin-left:8px;margin-right:8px;">
               <h3>Email Events</h3>                    
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptEmailEvents" runat="server" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div id="EmailEvent<%#Eval("EmailEventId")%>" data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="d" data-collapsed="true">
                                <div>
                                    <h3>Event: <%# Eval("EventType.Name") %> </h3>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    Response : <%# Eval("Response") %>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    Resend Attempt : <%# Eval("ResendAttempt") %>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    Click URL : <asp:HyperLink ID="hlClickURL" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ClickURL") %>' Text= '<%# Eval("ClickURL") %>' />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    Reason : <%# Eval("Reason") %>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    Bounce Type : <%# Eval("BounceType") %>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    Bounce Status : <%# Eval("BounceStatus") %>
                                </div>
                                    <div>
                                    SmtpMessageId : <%# Eval("SmtpMessageId") %>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    TimeStamp : <%# Eval("TimeStamp") %>
                                </div>       
                                <div>
                                    Event Tags : <%# Eval("csTags") %>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </div>
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand but how are you binding this repeater?

Comment: How are you binding this repeater? The second div data is a child of the first one? If so, you can bind the second div data in the itemcommand event of the first div data event

Comment: It's bound in the code behind  rep = (Repeater)EmailView.FindControl("rptEmailEvents");
            rep.DataSource = _email.EmailEvents.ToList();
            rep.DataBind();

Comment: There may be issue in generating Ids of Div inside <ItemTemplate> tag at line i.e. <div id="EmailEvent<%#Eval("EmailEventId")%>" ...

Comment: SanjeevRai, No it generated the id's fine. I forgot to mention the rows are there  when you inspect the elements in chrome you see all the records there. It's just not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing double quotes to single quotes at the following line in your code:
    ".

i.e. use `'EmailEvent<%#Eval("EmailEventId")%>'` insteed of `"EmailEvent<%#Eval("EmailEventId")%>"`.

Hope this will help!

Comment: No As I said the id is generated fine , example of the output  <div id="EmailEvent-9223372036854775791" data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="d" data-collapsed="true" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-collapsed">

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. under the second collapsible div:
" data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="d" data-collapsed="true">
I was missing the Header

#### Something

this is required because it will be built around this tag the collapsible control.